# IOS Push notification actions when app is killed/closed/not open

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Hi I'm working in a chat app, when a push notification arrives I've configure some actions like "mark as read" or "Reply" within the notification. Everything works if the app is on the foreground or running in the background. However when the app is closed/killed, the notification arrives but the actions are not being triggered. What's the best approach for this situation ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you apps awakes from killed/closed/not open state. The didReceiveNotification will not be called instead didFinishLaunching will be called. So you have to check if there is data of notification or not when the didFinishLaunching is called. You can check like this.

```swift
If (launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any]) != nil {
  .... Do your code for notification handling

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I'm trying to trigger an action directly from the notification without opening the app. The flow goes like this: App is killed, 1. User receives a notification 2. user swipes down (to enable notification action) 3. User selects "Reply message" action, 4. inputs the text 5. Taps send.  However if the app is not launched this notification actions don't work. Once the app is loaded it works smoothly. Thanks